# How to match a string with `\xXXXX` and `\uXXXX`

Tags: ruby, string, unicode

I have a string that contains `\xXXXX` and `\uXXXX`:

```
str = "\nDefault\nRouterRandom=\x9Db\u0012\xD3,\x92r\xFC o\u007F\x9B+\u0005I`\nWebInit=1\n"
```

I want to delete the content:

```
"RouterRandom=\x9Db\u0012\xD3,\x92r\xFC o\u007F\x9B+\u0005I`\n"
```

How can I match the string or delete it? I tried:

```
content = str.sub(/RouterRandom=.*WebInit/, "")
```

It returns errors:

```
E:/Automation/experiment/ruby_test/string_test.rb:119:in `sub': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
from E:/Automation/experiment/ruby_test/string_test.rb:119:in `block in <top (required)>'
from E:/Automation/experiment/ruby_test/string_test.rb:110:in `open'
from E:/Automation/experiment/ruby_test/string_test.rb:110:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `invalid byte sequence` because of invalid characters in your string.  You can replace invalid characters in your string first:

```
 content = str.encode( 'UTF-8', invalid: :replace )
```

Then split by newlines:

```
 content = content.split( "\n" )
```

Delete the offending element in the array by index:

```
 content.delete_at( 2 )
```

And then finally join the array back together into a newline delimited string:

```
 new_str = content.join( "\n" )
 # => "\nDefault\nWebInit=1"
```

Comment: It returns:     `in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)` when split

Comment: Did you first execute the first line I had?  What is the output of "content" before you call `split`?

Comment: I don't see you executing this line before the split:   `content = content.encode( 'UTF-8', invalid: :replace )`

Comment: `config_file="RT2880_Settings.dat"
content    = ""
open(config_file, "r") { |f|
  puts "输出配置文件内容:".encode("GBK")
  content = f.read
  p content  
       p content.encode("UTF-8", {:ivalid => :replace}) 
  p arr = content.split("\n")
}`

Comment: Copy and paste this into irb:   "\nDefault\nRouterRandom=\x9Db\u0012\xD3,\x92r\xFC o\u007F\x9B+\u0005I`\nWebInit=1\n".encode( 'UTF-8', invalid: :replace ).split( "\n" )

Comment: IRB is OK,but failed  `ruby filename.rb`in windows cmd